# Angularjs create scope object using Object.create

Tags: angularjs, prototype, angularjs-scope

I am learning AngularJS by building a web application. Have a prototype object in my service module (in the fiddle, I have mocked it within the controller).

Now when I try to update the child element - repeatableInfo - in the fiddle, it's not set. My guess is, in JavaScript objects are passed as reference. When Object.create is used, a new copy of the object is created and all the properties become prototype properties?

```
    var apiData={};
apiData.formObjectProto = {
    'commonInfo': '',
    'repeatableInfo': [
        {'aInfo': ''}
     ]
};

$scope.mainObj = Object.create(apiData.formObjectProto);
```

When it's replaced as below, everything works.

```
 var apiData={};
apiData.formObjectProto = {
    'commonInfo': '',
    'repeatableInfo': [
        {'aInfo': ''}
     ]
};

//$scope.mainObj = Object.create(apiData.formObjectProto);
$scope.mainObj = {
    'commonInfo': '',
    'repeatableInfo': [
        {'aInfo': ''}
     ]
};
```

So my question, can we not used OOP concept in angular? Or there is something I am missing. Please help

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmohta/qvCjm/12/)

**Update 1**

Using the below helps. So, Object.create() is not recommended, but rather use angular.copy() to create a clone of prototype object?

```
$scope.mainObj = angular.copy(apiData.formObjectProto);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to better to conform to angular's set of design pattern a different approach should be used to be able to new up a new instance of that map on each injection.

```
var deps, appModule;
deps = [];
appModule = angular.module('myApp', deps);
appModule.factory('myAppFactory', function() {

    var factory = {};

    factory.formObjectProto = {
        'commonInfo': '',
        'repeatableInfo': [
            {'aInfo': ''}
         ]
    };

    return factory;
});

appModule.controller('myAppCtrl', function ($scope, myAppFactory) {
    $scope.mainObj = myAppFactory;
    console.log('myAppCtrl# $scope.mainObj is: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.mainObj));

});

appModule.controller('oneInfoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('oneInfo.aInfo', function (newValue, oldValue){
        console.info('oneInfoCtrl watch# New value of oneInfo.aInfo is: ' + newValue);
    });

    $scope.$watch('mainObj.commonInfo', function (newValue, oldValue){
        console.info('mainObj.commonInfo watch# New value of commonInfo (present in $parent) is: ' + newValue);
    });
});
```

This will accomplish what you're doing in your update but conforming more closely to OOP principles.